# Average of averages from joining two tables

Tags: mysql

Looking for other ways to write a query that finds for each student the average of averages in each subject.

My query is working fine, I'm looking to learn from alternate approaches.

For example: the  grades of me(aka Error404) are:

- **Algebra:** first exam: 99, second exam: 97, third exam: 96 ---> **Average:** 97.3333
- **Machine-learning:** first exam: 95, second exam: 94, third exam: 100 ---> **Average:** 96.3333
- **Data science:** first exam: 91, second exam: 91.5, third exam: 93 ---> **Average:** 91.8333

I want AVG(97.3333,96.3333,91.8333)=95.1666

**Students table:**

```
  pk-INT           VARCHAR             VARCHAR
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
| StudentID | StudentFirstName | StudentLastName |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
|         1 | agam             | rafaeli         |
|         2 | amir             | aizinger        |
|         3 | avi              | caspi           |
|         4 | avia             | wolf            |
+-----------+------------------+-----------------+
```

**Tests table:**

```
  PK-VARCHR    PK-VARCHR     PK&FK-INT   INT
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| TestDate   | ClassName  | StudentID | Grade |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
| 2017-07-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    88 |
| 2017-08-02 | Algo       |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    80 |
| 2017-09-01 | Algebra    |         1 |    97 |
| 2017-09-01 | Set-theory |         1 |    85 |
| 2017-09-04 | Calcules   |         1 |    86 |
| 2016-05-03 | Set-theory |         2 |    84 |
| 2016-07-02 | Calcules   |         2 |    89 |
| 2016-07-04 | Algo       |         2 |    83 |
| 2016-07-05 | Algebra    |         2 |    79 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         3 |    99 |
| 2016-07-02 | Algo       |         3 |    97 |
| 2016-07-03 | Calcules   |         3 |    96 |
| 2016-09-03 | Set-theory |         3 |    95 |
| 2016-06-03 | Algebra    |         4 |    78 |
+------------+------------+-----------+-------+
```

**Output:**

```
+------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| StudentFirstName | StudentLastName | AVG(average) |
+------------------+-----------------+--------------+
| agam             | rafaeli         |  87.20832500 |
| amir             | aizinger        |  83.75000000 |
| avi              | caspi           |  96.75000000 |
| avia             | wolf            |  79.75000000 |
| ben              | moskovich       |  80.50000000 |
| chen             | segalovich      |  90.50000000 |
| dana             | levy            |  72.00000000 |
| daniel           | marcus          |  88.00000000 |
| daphna           | chwarts         |  90.25000000 |
| david            | cohen           |  87.75000000 |
+------------------+-----------------+--------------+
```

**My query:**

```
SELECT  StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, AVG(average)
FROM
(
SELECT   StudentFirstName, StudentLastName, AVG(Grade) AS average
FROM tests 
INNER JOIN students ON tests.StudentID=students.StudentID
GROUP BY StudentFirstName, StudentLastName,ClassName) AS t
GROUP BY StudentFirstName, StudentLastName;
```

## SAMPLE DATA

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS error404;
CREATE DATABASE error404;
USE error404
CREATE TABLE students
(
    StudentID        INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    StudentFirstName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentLastName  VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO students (StudentFirstName,StudentLastName) VALUES
('agam'  , 'rafaeli'), ('amir'  , 'aizinger'), ('avi'   , 'caspi'),
('avia'  , 'wolf ');
CREATE TABLE tests
(
    testid    INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    TestDate  DATE,
    ClassName VARCHAR(25),
    StudentID INT NOT NULL,
    Grade     INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (testid),
    KEY (StudentID)
);
INSERT INTO tests (TestDate,ClassName,StudentID,Grade) VALUES
('2017-07-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 88 ), ('2017-08-02', 'Algo'       , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 80 ), ('2017-09-01', 'Algebra'    , 1 , 97 ),
('2017-09-01', 'Set-theory' , 1 , 85 ), ('2017-09-04', 'Calcules'   , 1 , 86 ),
('2016-05-03', 'Set-theory' , 2 , 84 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Calcules'   , 2 , 89 ),
('2016-07-04', 'Algo'       , 2 , 83 ), ('2016-07-05', 'Algebra'    , 2 , 79 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 3 , 99 ), ('2016-07-02', 'Algo'       , 3 , 97 ),
('2016-07-03', 'Calcules'   , 3 , 96 ), ('2016-09-03', 'Set-theory' , 3 , 95 ),
('2016-06-03', 'Algebra'    , 4 , 78 );
```

Comment: Are you looking for a *better* approach? Can the approach be *worse*, as long as its different and still gives the correct answer? Are there any specific restrictions on the approach (can't use `AVG`, can't use aggregate functions at all, etc)? Out of curiosity, why are you looking for this, when you've got a perfectly good, perfectly clean approach already?

Comment: @RDFozz The approach can be *worse* as long as its different and still gives the correct answer, there aren't restrictions on the approach, I'm looking for this because I want to see& learn.

Comment: An "average of averages" is _not_ mathematically correct if each exam is to be given the same weight.  It _happened_ to work in your example since there were the same number of exams in each class.

Comment: `AVG(x)` == `SUM(x)/COUNT(*)`  -- Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Is it possible to execute this query using `SELECT` only once?

Comment: @Error404 - I don't think so (unless you want the student's average test score across all classes, as Rick James suggested, instead of the student's average class grade). Multiple queries or sub-queries of some sort are basically required.

Comment: @RickJames - I'm assuming the OP is looking for each student's average course grade (80 in History, 90 in Physics, 100 in Math, average course grade is 90), not their average test score across all classes (History had 10 tests, Physics and Math both had 1 each, average test score across all classes is 82.5). I've never heard of any metric where that would be relevant - I'd go so far as to say it's "super-freaky"

Comment: @Error404 - Since you need an average of averages, you must do two `SELECTs` to get the two `GROUP BYs`.  Is there a problem?  Aren't we talking milliseconds?  Isn't "My query:(after edit)" working correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that someone will have a really innovative take on this (maybe something that uses binary arithmetic somehow, I don't know).

I can think of two approaches to this. The first is basically a joke; the second isn't terribly useful, but at least is a serious answer (so, don't give up reading during the joke!).

#### The "professor doesn't look at the code" method

The first one is for the computer science student who can't figure out the right way to do it, and has to get the computer to spit out the answer.

Note: this "approach" is *absolutely useless* outside of this basic concept. I suppose "Boss" could be substituted for "professor" - but this "solution" falls apart when there's more than a simple test set of data involved, or when you need to process a completely different set of data in a few minutes.

Here, you calculate the answer for each student manually from the data. Then, you create a SQL statement that has the right answers hard-coded into it. Fortunately, I could cheat as I have the right answers from the OP's own query. The future computer science dropout using this technique would probably do something similar - ask to see a classmate's results, so he could "make sure his were right."

```
SELECT 'agam' as StudentFirstName
      ,'rafaeli' as StudentLastName
      ,'89.083325' as `AVG(average)`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'amir','aizinger','83.75'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'avi','caspi','96.75'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'avia','wolf ','78'
;
```

#### The "what if there was no `AVG` function" method

This is more useful than the previous method (After all, I'm not sure you can make something less useful than the previous method!)

Here, we pretend the `AVG` function doesn't exist. There is more than one way to do this. You can calculate the individual averages for each class (total points for class/nbr of assignments for class), then the overall average (total of averages for each class/nbr of classes).

I'm going to do something a little more brain-stretching. Same basic concept, but only using the `SUM` function (that still exists, in my little fantasy) in one place.

A little math first:

The average for the grades from one class are *(G<sub>1</sub> + G<sub>2</sub> + ... + G<sub>n</sub>)/n*, where *G<sub>x</sub>* is the grade for assignment *x*, and *n* is the number of assignments for that class.

Similarly, the total average is *(A<sub>a</sub> + A<sub>b</sub> + ... A<sub>m</sub>)/m*, where *A<sub>x</sub>* is the average grade for class *x*, and *m* is the number of classes the student is taking.

Filling our first equation into the second, we get:

```
( (Ga1 + Ga2 + ... + Gan) / n
 +(Gb1 + Gb2 + ... + Gbq) / q
 + ...
 +(Gm1 + Gm2 + ... + Gmr) / r
) / m
```

which equals:

```
 (Ga1 + Ga2 + ... + Gan) / (n * m)
+(Gb1 + Gb2 + ... + Gbq) / (q * m)
+ ...
+(Gm1 + Gm2 + ... + Gmr) / (r * m)
```

which equals:

```
 Ga1/(n*m) + Ga2/(n*m) + ... + Gan/(n*m)
+Gb1/(q*m) + Gb2/(q*m) + ... + Gbq/(q*m)
+ ...
+Gm1/(r*m) + Gm2/(r*m) + ... + Gmr/(r*m)
```

Or, in English: the average grade can be calculated by dividing each grade (*Gij*) by the number of assignments in that class and by the number of classes, then adding them all together.

This query does that. It uses subqueries to determine the number of classes each student is taking, and the number of tests they had in each class.

```
SELECT s.StudentFirstName
      ,s.StudentLastName
      ,SUM(g.Grade / (c.nbrClasses * t.nbrTests)) as `AVG(average)`
  FROM students s
         INNER JOIN tests g ON (s.StudentID = g.StudentID)
         INNER JOIN (SELECT StudentID, COUNT(*) as nbrClasses
                       FROM (SELECT StudentID, ClassName
                               FROM tests
                              GROUP BY StudentID, ClassName
                            ) classes
                      GROUP BY StudentID
                    ) c ON (s.StudentID = c.StudentID)
         INNER JOIN (SELECT StudentID, ClassName, COUNT(*) as nbrTests
                       FROM tests
                      GROUP BY StudentID, ClassName
                    ) t ON (    g.StudentID = t.StudentID
                            AND g.ClassName = t.ClassName
                           )
 GROUP BY s.StudentFirstName, s.StudentLastName
;
```

There is a slight difference with this result set. The original query gave the average for Agam Rafaeli as 89.083325; this final query rounds that to four digits to the right of the decimal point, yielding 89.0833. Someone more knowledgeable in MySQL might know how to prevent that.

Here's a [db-fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5kysK1XyewaFxBhwcGEa8/0) showing the original query in action, along with the above two alternates.

FYI: as the original query gives equal weight to all tests in each class, and equal weight to the average grade for each class in figuring out the answer, I have done the same. Someone noted that you'd need a different (simpler, actually) solution if you wanted the final student average to give equal weight to all tests across all classes. True, but that's not my understanding of the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a little more readable by using the OVER clause and a temporary table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT StudentID,ClassName,AVG(grade) OVER (PARTITION BY classname,StudentID) AS AVGforClass
INTO #Average_for_each_class_by_student
FROM tests

SELECT StudentID,AVG(AVGforClass) AS AVGoverall 
INTO #Average_for_each_student_over_all_classes
FROM #Average_for_each_class 
GROUP BY StudentID
```

That'll give you one table with averages for each class for each student and one table of averages for each student over all classes. You could then join the students table with that to get the names for each student.

```
SELECT s.StudentFirstName,s.StudentLastName,a.AVGoverall 
FROM #Average_for_each_student_over_all_classes a INNER JOIN students s ON a.StudentID = s.StudentID
```

This way if you ever have to come back to this SQL script, you can easily read and access each part of the script. (e.g. your client or teacher changes their mind and wants a students average for a specific class)

[The SQL OVER() clause - when and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218902/the-sql-over-clause-when-and-why-is-it-useful)

Comment: MySQL doesn't appear to support window functions quite yet (I see man pages for version 8.0, but that's not the official current release at this time).

Comment: Oopsie, didn't realize this was MySQL. Thanks!

Comment: It's a good answer for the general question - just thought I should point that out in case someone was expecting something that would work directly in MySQL. And, of course, once MySQL 8.0 is out, windowing functions should be an option.